# set blank in the field when its contain value 0 (zero)

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am working with `iReport` and generate around 20 pdf report also.Now I want all the field blank in the report where its contain value 0 (zero).

For that I set text field expression with the code

```java
$F{diamondQty}.doubleValue() == 0.0 ? null : $F{diamondQty}.doubleValue()
```

and enable *`Blank when null`* option of the field.

It's working fine but require to do same for all the field of all 20 reports.

Is there any other better solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a [FormatFactory](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/FormatFactory.html).
A format factory allows you to specify your own date and number formats. You can set it as a report property (`formatFactoryClass`) , or set it as a parameter (`REPORT_FORMAT_FACTORY`)

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

1. Click **Window >> Prefereces**
2. Select **Capabilities**
3. Check **Development**
4. Click **OK**

Next:

1. Open the Project Explorer
2. Right-click Project name
3. Select **Properties**
4. Select **Java Build Path**
5. Click the **Source** tab
6. Click **Add Folder**
7. Select **Create New Folder**
8. Set Folder Name to: `src`
9. Click **Finish**
10. Select **src**
11. Click **OK**
12. Set Default output folder: Project Name/`build`
13. Click **OK**

Create a report as usual (with a text field that uses a date, either a parameter or a field), then:

1. Select the report in the **Outline** panel
2. Open the **Properties** panel
3. Set **Format Factory Class** to: `com.company.reports.ReportFormatFactory`

Next, create some source code inside the "src" directory in a package (folder) named `com.company.reports`. Paste the following into a file named `ReportFormatFactory.java` that is saved in that directory:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.DefaultFormatFactory;

/**
 * Delegates creation of date and number formatters to JasperReports' default
 * formatters. This class ensures that dates are formatted consistently across
 * all reports.
 */
public class ReportFormatFactory extends DefaultFormatFactory {
  /**
   * Returns a DateFormat instance that creates dates in YYYY/MM/dd format.
   *
   * @param pattern Unused.
   * @param locale Passed to the DefaultFormatFactory instance.
   * @param timezone Passed to the DefaultFormatFactory instance.
   *
   * @return An object that can format dates.
   */
  @Override
  public DateFormat createDateFormat(
    String pattern, Locale locale, TimeZone timezone ) {
    return super.createDateFormat( "YYYY/MM/dd", locale, timezone );
  }
}
```

When you run the report, the date should be formatted as `YYYY/MM/dd`.

If you want to change the format (e.g., to `dd/MM/YYYY`), update the date format line in the source code and then restart Jaspersoft Studio (the classloader does not seem to reload the ReportFormatFactory class after modification).

To avoid having to restart each time the date format changes, use a resource bundle:

1. Create a new project folder called `i18n`

   1. ​Right-click on the project name
   2. Select **New >> Folder**
   3. Set Folder name to `i18n`
   4. Click **Finish**
2. Right-click on **i18n**
3. Select **New >> Other**
4. Expand **Messages Editor**
5. Select **ResourceBundle**
6. Click **Next**
7. Set the name to: `ReportsLocale`
8. Add a **Locale** (e.g., en_US)
9. Click **Finish**

Add the **i18n** directory to the build process:

1. Right-click **i18n**
2. Select **Build Path >> Configure Build Path**
3. Click **Add Folder**
4. Check **i18n**
5. Click **OK**
6. Click **OK** again

Change the `createDateFormat` method as follows:

```
  @Override
  public DateFormat createDateFormat(
    String pattern, Locale locale, TimeZone timezone ) {
    String dateFormat = DATE_FORMAT_DEFAULT;

   try {
     ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle( "EducationReports" );
     String df = rb.getString( DATE_FORMAT );

     if( df != null ) {
       dateFormat = df;
     }
   }
   catch( Exception e ) {
     // If the resource bundle isn't found, use the default date format.
     // TODO: Pass this exception into a logger.
   }

    return super.createDateFormat( dateFormat, locale, timezone );
  }
```

And add these constants to the class definition (immediately after the **`public class`** declaration, around line 15/16):

```
  private final static String DATE_FORMAT = "date.format";
  private final static String DATE_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "YYYY/MM/dd";
```

Restart Jaspersoft Studio, then:

1. Edit the **ReportsLocale** file
2. Add a `date.format` property
3. Set the property to `dd/MM/YYYY`
4. Set the property value for all locales.

When the report is run, the date should look like 29/02/1976, for example.

You can adapt this to change the field value as required.

Comment: I can't understand this answer?, the question is about removing values if they are 0, you are posting about formatting date's, ok you can create your own class in java to display empty string on 0,  but this answer seems a bit far away from a solution of the 0 problem, maybe edit it to contain a NumberFormat example

Comment: Going point, Petter. Instead of overriding `createDateFormat` from the superclass, it requires overriding `createNumberFormat`. I'll revise as time allows.

Comment: Thanks, if you ping me when done, I'm always happy to up vote good answers in jasper reports section